# postfixのメール送信間隔を1秒未満設定について

Tags: postfix

初心者で質問が荒くて申し込みありませんが、ご存知の方がいらっしゃればお教え願います。
postfixにて色々ネットで調べ、試しているのですが、どうしてもメール送信間隔を1秒未満に設定することができません。
postfixの各パラメータでは1秒が指定可能な最小値なのでしょうか？
何か代替手段(どこかにsleepシェルを強制的に起動など)でも構いませんので手段があればお教え願います。

Comment: ご自身でも「荒くて」と書かれてますが、質問が大雑把なので回答が付きにくいかもしれません。具体的なコードや設定ファイルを提示できますか？そうすれば詳しい方からの回答が来ると思いますよ！

Comment: 「メール送信間隔」とはどのようなことを言っていますか？具体的なパラメータ名がわかっているのなら書いてください。

Comment: 皆様コメントありがとうございます。    メール送信間隔と書いてあるのは、maillogに出力される(delay)  になります。例えばメールを同時に10通postfixに送信し、postfixは中継サーバー的な役割として他サーバーにリレーします。このdelay間隔を0.5秒など一秒未満の一定間隔にしたく考えております。(ネットで調べ、配送間隔(destination_rate_delay)を設定して試しているのですが最小として1秒しか指定できませんでした)

Comment: ちなみに、maillogに出力される "delay"　は送信などの処理時間が出力されています。処理時間の内訳は"delays"に出力されています。 delays=a/b/c/d, とあるとき，a，b，c，d は　a: queueに入る前のメッセージが送信されてくるまでの時間　b: queueに入っている時間 c: サーバへ接続を確立するのにかかった時間 d: 送信にかかった時間 英語ですがここが詳しく書いてあります。http://oliver.net.au/?p=211